# irb readline and rvm ruby 1.9.3 on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, readline, irb

I am using os x Lion and successfully installed and linked readine using homebrew. Furthermore I successfully compiled ruby 1.9.3 using rvm with readline support.

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

However, when I start irb and try to input accented chars (using option + e for example), no character appears.

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I get accented characters in IRB (or PRY) ?

Comment: First, just to make sure, you are typing a complete accented character, like option+e e, not just the modifier option+e, right?

Comment: Assuming that's not the problem, you have to figure out whether the problem is with ruby, irb, Terminal, or readline. Type an é into another window, then copy it and paste it into the irb window, and see what happens. Then try running ruby instead of irb, running irb --noreadline, in each case both typing and pasting the é.

Comment: I am pressing option +e e indeed. And in the terminal the accented e does appear. As soon as I enter irb en press option+e e, no character appears.

Comment: OK, but what about all the other things I asked you to try? Without that information, nobody can help you debug the problem.